# Phantomjs loads pages slowly

Tags: connection, phantomjs

I'm new into phantomjs, trying it on a standard centOS server (with httpd etc installed, but no modified settings apart from nameservers set to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).

I'm using the default loadspeed.js file (be it renamed). However, page speeds appear to be extremely slow. Here's an example:

```
$ phantomjs phantomjs.js  http://www.google.com/
starting
Loading time 90928 msec

$ phantomjs phantomjs.js http://173.194.67.138/ #(one of google's public ips)
starting
Loading time 30204 msec
```

When I load any url on the server (such as http://something.be ), loadtime is 141msec:

```
 $ phantomjs phantomjs.js http://something.be
 starting
 Loading time 141 msec
```

Does anyone have a clue what causes my connection to be this slow? The connection itself is fine, wget takes seconds to download a file of several MB.

Also, when I run the exact same script on OSX locally for Google, this is the output:

```
 phantomjs phantomjs.js http://google.com/
 starting
 Loading time 430 msec
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Found it - seems like ipv6 was the culprit.

I disabled it temporarily by running the following:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6 
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/disable_ipv6
```

Testing confirms:

```
$ phantomjs phantomjs.js http://google.com
starting
Loading time 230 msec
```

Comment: Setting the IPV6 setting to "Link-local only" worked for me.  How annoying.

Comment: Wow, I'm curious about how did you found this quirk. You should get a golden medal for this find. I went from 48 seconds to 1 second. Thanks a lot

Comment: Some knowledge of networking and knowledge of the fact that ipv6 wasn't assigned to the box helped. :)

Comment: How to revert this change ? (enable ipv6)

Comment: Do the same with ```echo 0``` instead of ```echo 1```

Comment: This should go in `/etc/sysctl.conf` as `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1` and applied with `sudo sysctl -p`, to persist across reboots.

Answer (score 8):

Well, in my case, the page was waiting for some GET requests and was not able to reach the requests' server and it kept waiting for long. I could only figure it out when i used the remote debugger option.

```
phantomjs --remote-debugger-port=9000 loadspeed.js <some_url>
```

and inside the loadspeed.js file

```
page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
    console.log('requested: ' + JSON.stringify(req, undefined, 4));
};

page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
    console.log('received: ' + JSON.stringify(res, undefined, 4));
};
```

and then loading localhost:9000 in any webkit browser (safari/chrome) and seeing the console logs where i could figure out it was waiting for some failed requests for a long time.

TO BYPASS THIS - REDUCE THE TIMEOUT:

```
page.settings.resourceTimeout = 3000; //in secs
```

and things were very quick after that. Hope this helps