# Selenium and PhantomJS takes 30 seconds to open each link

Tags: c#, performance, selenium, phantomjs, screen-scraping

I am trying to open a website and grab some data using Selenium with PhantomJS, however it takes a lot of time to open a website (about 30 second). And every time I open other link I have to wait 30+Seconds. What is wrong with my code ?

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        IWebDriver browser = new PhantomJSDriver();

        var URL = "http://www.cbssports.com/nba/playerrankings ";

        browser.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);

        //Position
        var title = browser.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".tableTitle"));
        Console.WriteLine(title.First().Text);

        Console.Read();
        }
```

Things I have tried to do:
1.[Set PhantomJS proxy type to none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948698/how-to-set-the-phantomjsoptions-in-selenium-for-proxy-type)
2.[Disable internet option: automatically detect settings](https://plus.google.com/+MatthiasG%C3%B6tzke/posts/9v9BMCJj2k6)
3.[Disable IPv6 protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684185/phantomjs-loads-pages-slowly)

[PhantomJS release notes](http://phantomjs.org/release-1.9.html) claim, that there are some known issues with network performance on Microsoft Windows. According to release notes, solution is to set proxy type to none, however that doesn't work.

Comment: Which selenium and phantomjs versions are you using? Thanks.

Comment: There's a trick to getting phantomjs to not load all the assets (you don't need css, images, etc.) I don't remember it offhand but if you google for it you will find it.

Comment: I use PhantomJS 1.9.8  and Selenium 2.44.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait 30 seconds because you haven't defined timeouts which are 30 seconds as default. You should use this predefined driver service.

```
        var phantomJSDriverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        IWebDriver browser = new PhantomJSDriver(phantomJSDriverService);
        browser.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

The default timeout for Selenium is 30 seconds. You are using `browser.FindElements()` (the plural version), which will wait the full 30 seconds before continuing!

You can reduce the timeout with `browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait()`, or you can use explicit timeouts.